# oop array with word in it

Tags: php, pdo

I currntly have this:

```
$preparedStatement->execute(array(':link' => $link, ':title' => $title, ':id' => $id));
```

I need to add /page/ infront of $link .
I tried this, but it does not work.

```
$preparedStatement->execute(array(':link' => "/page/$link", ':title' => $title, ':id' => $id));
```

Comment: Define "does not work"? It set you cat on fire? It ran off?

Comment: [`"/page/" . $link` (proper PHP variable concatenation)](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/proper-inline-php-variable-concatenation/)

Comment: @DanFromGermany In PHP, double quotes allow for variables within the string to be evaluated and expanded, so this should work.

Comment: @Dan but it's dirty programing, no one should be doing it in serious programing.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Personally, I think it looks cleaner when you have 10 variables being interspersed throughout the string. Regardless, I'm still curious why it wasn't working.

Comment: @Dan look at the syntax highlighting on stackoverflow, the variables get highlighted when outside of quotes, but don't get highlighted when inside the quotes. There are also situation where variables in quotes fail. for example: `$T = 'one'; $TE = 'two'; echo "$TTE$TE$T$TT$T$E$TE$TETE$TTEE$$TTEE";` ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56599/discussion-between-dan-and-danfromgermany).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try concatenating -

```
$preparedStatement->execute(array(':link' => "/page/".$link, ':title' => $title, ':id' => $id));
```

or create the variable ahead of time -

```
$link = "/page/foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following prints '/page/index.php' for me, so perhaps you are accessing the array incorrectly?

```
$link = 'index.php';
$title = 'My Page';
$a = array(':link' => "/page/$link", ':title' => $title);
echo $a[':link'];
```

Comment: I doubt he is accessing it at all, it's a prepared statement, PDO is accessing it.

Comment: Hmm, what else could it be? Is there a flag that disables evaluating variables in double-quoted strings?

Comment: Please see coding standards like PSR or ZF, they all suggest not to put variables simply into quotes. It leads to errors when doing so.